# How to extract text from command result in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a script where I am executing

`connmanctl services`

it gives me:

> A0 Wired ethernet_abcdefghijkl_cable

I want to extract `ethernet_abcdefghijkl_cable` and put it in a variable.

How can I do that?

I tried following so far but didn't work:

```
x="$(connmanctl services)"

echo "$x" | cut -d' ' -f 3
```

Comment: what does your `cut` command return ?  Its working for me, perhaps you may want to append `2>&1` to `connmanctl` command. Its possible that its printing to stderr ,although I am not sure.

Comment: It is working for me too.

Comment: @PS. I would just get empty return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# store command output in an array
read -ra array < <(conmanctl services)

var=${array[2]}
```

no need to involve cut